# Deleted database from phpadmin -can't access site

Tags: mysql, web

site hosted on 1&1 - Couldn't access my site suddenly one day giving me some weird error.

Checked the console -source codes still there but the database, accessible through phpadmin, has been wiped clean.
and i have no backups whatsoever.

I just want the basic structure back.
can i recreate it through the source code?
(FYI- i didn't develop it and the developer has  disappeared)

Heres the error I am getting while accessing the site.
[Error on site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPvkK.png)

Comment: Are you making use of an open source platform?

Comment: @PeterM - you mean for development?, probably - i actually didn't develop the site , i hired a developer to do so who is now AWOL.
I can see the source codes in my console webspace.

Comment: I mean something like wordpress or drupal or something else, that way getting a blank DB schema isn't to hard. if not you might want to take a look at the sourcode and search for `install` or `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Maybe your host provider 1&1 has automatic backups of your database?